# Trigger Pixel Tracking Only When Form Submission Complete

Tags: html, form-submit, google-forms, facebook-pixel

I think my question is somehow common but I can't find any on this forum or in Google.

Lets say I got a registration form generate using Google Form. And after successful submission, user will be redirected to another homepage. (not a thank you page)

Here's how the HTML button looks like with the tracking code:

```
<div class="contactInput submitButton">
    <input class="button" type="submit" value="Join Us" onclick="fbq('track', 'SubmitApplication');">
</div>
```

But the problem is, whoever click the button trigger that event tracking. **How can I trigger Facebook Pixel Event code only when the submission is successful?**